# How to decrease the wait time for NoSuchElementException in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

In some cases, i know element will not be displayed. but its waiting ~30 Secs.

How to decrease wait time for `NoSuchElementException` in selenium?

Sample code:

```
String name;
        try {    
            name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPath")).getText();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            name = "Name not displayed";
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a real example that works just like you described? I'm quite sure that provided code should immediately raise an exception. Described behavior available only if to use `WebdriverWait` + `ExpectedConditions`

Comment: Try block is inside the loop of 626 iterations, But expecting only 200+ values to be found and write the name into an excel file for future reference. Have used implicit wait for 30 secs after opening browser.

Comment: you have to use explicit waits described in the webdriver documentation http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: Remove the implicit wait and use explicit/fluent waits  only for the statements required and in general do not mix the two. The delay is caused by the implicit wait.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for setting the implitic wait time for your driver:

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

For simple cases thats ok to use, for more advanced automation, I'd change it to an explicit wait (using `WebDriverWait`).

More on waits:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Use [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to decrease waiting time ex (wait 5 seconds):

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use explicit wait for this scenario but have to be careful with the expected conditions being used.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```

Sometimes visibilityOf(Name) will not work since mostly finding of webelement name needs the findElement statement to be used.

WebElement name=driver.findElement(Locator);

This step may fail if element is not present!